# Prove that $\pi > 24\small{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Prove that $\pi > 24\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}$.

I tried using trig but I couldn't solve it. A hint I was given is to use half angle identities. This should be easy for someone who is experienced in inequalities, but I'm looking for a "low power" solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Try $(\pi/24)^2>2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}$ etc...

Comment: Is it root of 24 power or 24 multiplied by the root?

Comment: I guess is multiplied

Comment: The expression on RHS is equal to $48 sin\frac{\pi}{48} $ , which is the circumference of what polygon inside a circle...

Comment: @Alan If you have proof for this, it qualifies as an answer, since $\sin x < x \ \forall x > 0$ ($\triangle$)

Comment: Can you come up with a polynomial with integer coefficients which has your right side as a root?

Answer (score 12):

$$\sqrt{3}=2\sin \frac{\pi}{3}$$

$$2+\sqrt{3}=2\left(1+\sin \frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$

$$2+\sqrt{3}=2\left(1+\cos \frac{\pi}{6}\right)$$

$$2+\sqrt{3}=2\left(2\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{12}\right)$$

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}=2\cos \frac{\pi}{12}$$

$$2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}=2(1+\cos \frac{\pi}{12})$$

$$2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}=2\left(2\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{24}\right)$$

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}=2\cos \frac{\pi}{24}$$

$$2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}=2\left(1-\cos \frac{\pi}{24}\right)$$

$$2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}=2\left(2\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{48}\right)$$

$$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}=2\sin \frac{\pi}{48}$$

$$24\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}=48\sin \frac{\pi}{48}$$

$$\pi > 24\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}} = 48\sin \frac{\pi}{48}$$

$$\pi > 48\sin \frac{\pi}{48}$$

$$2\pi > 96\sin \frac{\pi}{48}=48\left(2\sin \frac{\pi}{48}\right)=48\times \text{side length of regular 48-gon}$$

True because perimeter of circumscribed circle of regular 48-gon is > perimeter of polygon.